# Get the text of a Span element contained inside a DIV element - which was drag-dropped into another Div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a DIV element which is draggable, inside this DIV, I have a span element with some text.

```
<div draggable="true" style="border:5px solid blue; height:30px; width:150px;">
    <span>Value123</span>
</div>
```

This DIV does not have any ID, or Class Name. **I am not allowed to add any attribute** in this DIV.

I am dragging this DIV into another DIV (Drop zone).

```
<div id="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" 
style="border: 2px solid blue; height:200px; width:400px">
```

These are the two JavaScript functions.

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();                     
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    console.log(data); // How can I get the SPAN text here ????
}
```

I am getting blank in the console.

Is there any way to get the span text printed in the console after the first DIV is dragged into the second div ?

Here is the code for the full HTML Page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
      function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
      }
      
      function drop(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();                     
          var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
          console.log(data); // How can I get the SPAN text here ????
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div draggable="true" style="border:5px solid blue; height:30px; width:150px;">
        <span>Value123</span>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" 
    style="border: 2px solid blue; height:200px; width:400px">        
</body>    
a</html>
```

Comment: Could you please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `draggable` attribute to get the text:

Working snippet:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}



function drop(ev) {
  var data = $('div[draggable=true]').find('span').text();
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>




<div draggable="true" style="border:5px solid blue; height:30px; width:150px;">
  <span>Value123</span>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div id="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="border: 2px solid blue; height:200px; width:400px">
```

**For multiple draggable divs** a slight change in jquery code is needed.

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/uoLj78xw/

Comment: This will work if there is only 1 such DIV. What if I have multiple DIVs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **ondragstart** event listener on the **body tag** itself. Whenever the event is fired `e.target` will return the actual draggable div. Use `e.target.childNodes[1].innerHTML` to get the text inside the first child of that div. Just set the data using       `e.dataTransfer.setData('text', data);` and now you can read the data on drop event listener.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
  const data = e.target.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', data);
});

function drop(e) {
  e.target.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .d2 {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div draggable="true" style='height: 50px;width: 50px;border: 1px solid red;'>
    <span>
            hii
        </span>
  </div>
  <div draggable="true" style='height: 50px;width: 50px;border: 1px solid red;'>
    <span>
            bye
        </span>
  </div>
  <div class='d2' ondragover='dragOver(event)' ondrop='drop(event)'>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remember, if you pass an object to setData( ) or an HTML Element it will be converted to string. So, whatever conversion or data extraction you need to perform, do it before passing the value to setData( ) . You may pass object/multiple values, just structure it properly in JSON format and then you can parse the string into JSON object on the drop event.

Comment: Also, OP mentions that he is not allowed to add any attribute on this draggable DIV, so he cannot add  `ondragstart="drag(event)"` too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).